# "You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries." error while running an app on iOS simulator using flutter

Tags: flutter, simulator

My app was working fine before. But now it's showing an error **"error running pod install. error launching iPhone 13".**

So I tried "pod install" in the iOS folder, and it gave me this error,**"You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries."**

I tried flutter doctor and everything is fine there. But still it's showing that error. And I do not even code in Ruby, I just code in Flutter, but still suddenly it's showing that error. *I am using VS code. My simulator is iPhone 13 15.0 version.*